# No such file or directory: /uploads

Tags: python, flask, upload

I've looked at a couple of the other questions but can't figure out what is going wrong.  I get the following error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/uploads\MRRtest.csv'"  Can anyone help?  What is the difference between the forward and backward slashes on the error message?

Thanks

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['csv'])
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER



def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))
    return render_template('index.html')
```

My index.html template is as follows:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Flasky{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Upload File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What OS are you on? Also is this your full code? Where is the name MRRtest coming from?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and python 3.  I have an index html file for my view and MRRtest.csv is the file that I upload using that

Comment: Just realized the index file was in templates while my 'uploads' directory was in the same directory as the run.py file.  As such, I changed the UPLOAD FOLDER = to './uploads"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/uploads` means an absolute link (C:/upload), so you should use `upload/` instead.

Also, you can use the nice snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257725/5851179

```
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/uploads')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized from the comments that my uploads directory is in the same directory as my run.py file rather than the 'templates' directory that index.html is running from.  I modified the

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/uploads'
```

to

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads'
```

I'll now work on building the  "url for endpoint"

Thanks for your help.