# Form not valid in django

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Hi I am learning Django for a project and I am trying to upload a file along with a on option in dropdown list through a form using POST. 
Here are my files:

**views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .forms import UploadFileForm

# function to handle an uploaded file.
from save_uploaded_file import handle_uploaded_file


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return render(request, 'viewer_app/display_image.html')
        else:
            print('error')
            return render(request, 'viewer_app/index.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'viewer_app/index.html')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
    displayType = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

**save_uploaded_file.py**

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('static/viewer_app/temp.exr', 'wb+') as recieved_exr:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            recieved_exr.write(chunk)
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="formDiv" style="display:none;" class="form" >

    <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-style">

        <label for="browse">Upload file</label>
        <input type="file" value="Browse" id="brow" /><br></br>

        <label for="display">Display type</label>
        <select id="display-type" name="display">
            <option id="RGB1" value="RGB1">RGB1</option>
            <option id="RGB2" value="RGB2">RGB2</option>
            <option id="RGB3" value="RGB3">RGB3</option>
            <option id="RGB4" value="RGB4">RGB4</option>
        </select><br></br>

        <input type="submit" value="Show file" id="showimage"/><br></br>
        {% csrf_token %}        

    </form>
</div>
```

So, after I run the server to display the page and I select the upload and click submit, it doesn't upload and save the file and in the terminal I see the "error" text in the terminal which is displayed due to from.is_valid() not being true.

I tried to add `{{ form.errors }} {{ form.non_field_errors }}` to the html file but I still don't know exactly what is that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try writing "print(form._errors)" in the "else:" block of "form.is_valid():"  to display the exact error in the console. Maybe that will help. Or can you provide us with the what it displays in the console?

Comment: I added the print(form._errors) and the error message I get is:      

<ul class="errorlist"><li>displayType<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>       

[07/Aug/2017 22:07:25] "POST /viewer_app/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4467

Comment: As you can see that 2 fields are required and your form isn't bound to them. Things that you can do: 1) Make sure that those two are the only fields inside your form. 2) You can write print(request.POST) in "if request.method == 'POST':" block to make sure that data is at least coming from the index.html which will narrow the error to Django.

Comment: So as you can see in my form file, those are the only two fields I have in the form. After adding print(request.POST), I got a list which seems like the data is coming from the index.html: <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'PAAs20HYoLNSfsFUwntH3iGyFBuodIw5lIPOePPwvxuIDMX3PfWxiHaU9okdncxh'], u'display': [u'sRGB']}>. Now, I am not sure which part in my django is having a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also I can see the absence of name attributes inside your `<input>` tag and a potentially wrong name attribute inside your `<select>` tag. You should put the exact name of the field inside your html 's name attribute for the form to get bounded. Same goes for the `<select>` tags.

Try putting:

```
<input type="file" value="Browse" id="brow" name="file"/>
```

and

```
<select id="display-type" name="displayType">
```

and probably your problem will be solved.
If I may suggest, **why aren't you using the standard django template form tags, Such as `{{ form.as_p }}` ?** These methods are quite handy and will also handle the errors successfully. You should try using them. [check them here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options)

**EDIT**
You haven't given any choices attribute to you `ChoiceField` in your forms.py. Make sure to give a attribute `choices` as a tuple to your ChoiceField. It can be done as:

```
#import ugettext_lazy
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

#inside your form class
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (
        ('RGB1', _('RGB1')),
        ('RGB2', _('RGB2')),
        ('RGB3', _('RGB3')),
        #And so on
    )
    #First option in the tuple is stored in db. Second is displayed in Forms.
    displayType = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), required=True , choices = CHOICES)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

**EDIT 2:**

Get the file url as below,

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

url = static('viewer_app/temp.exr')
#See if temp.exr exists prior to this. Otherwise create a file manually  or through python.
```

Then open the file by supplying this url.

Again I would recommend you to check ModelForms. They'll completely eliminate the need to write files this way.

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: I added the names as you suggested, but then I get this error: <ul class="errorlist"><li>displayType<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. RGB1 is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>. But if you look at the html code RGB1 is one of the options in the list.

Comment: Yeah I helped with that part but then I get this error: IOError at /viewer_app/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/viewer_app/temp.exr'. If you look at the python code for handle_uploaded_file, temp.exr is the filename I am opening to write to, so I don't get the "no such file" error.

Comment: I recommend you open the file using "from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static". Giving a url like that might be causing a problem. I've explained it more clearly in another EDIT.

Comment: I tried that suggestion and used the static import in the save_uploaded_file.py, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I tried writing a file the way you are writing and it worked alright. It works even if you don't have a file created already( with open() ) does that for you. The only time I stumbled upon an error was when the directory I wanted to access through open wasn't created at all. The error I got was " [Errno 2] No such file or directory " ; traced back to the line " with open('static/viewer_app/temp.exr', 'wb+') as recieved_exr: " . Tell me if you're getting an error different from this.

Comment: Also, have you added a name attribute inside " <input type="file" value="Browse" id="brow" /> " yet? It should look like " <input type="file" value="Browse" id="brow" name="file" /> "

Comment: Actually the problem ended up being something else. I found it in this thread in answer 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637352/flask-ioerror-when-saving-uploaded-files/20257725#20257725